# :app:compileDebugAndroidTestKotling FAILED unresolved reference: className multi module project

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I am unsure of what is causing this issue. There are no compile time errors in Android Studio. This only occurs when I run an android test:

```
Task :app:compileDebugAndroidTestKotlin FAILED
e: C:\Users\alexl\Documents\Speak-Easy\app\src\androidTest\java\com\spark\chat\screen\AuthenticationScreen.kt: (4, 25): Unresolved reference: BaseScreen
e: C:\Users\alexl\Documents\Speak-Easy\app\src\androidTest\java\com\spark\chat\screen\AuthenticationScreen.kt: (6, 30): Unresolved reference: BaseScreen
e: C:\Users\alexl\Documents\Speak-Easy\app\src\androidTest\java\com\spark\chat\screen\AuthenticationScreen.kt: (9, 9): Unresolved reference: checkHint
e: C:\Users\alexl\Documents\Speak-Easy\app\src\androidTest\java\com\spark\chat\screen\AuthenticationScreen.kt: (13, 9): Unresolved reference: checkHint

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAndroidTestKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWGnU.png)

App builds fine normally when not running androidTest. I have a module with the package name com.spark.common. App package name is com.spark.chat. Not sure if that has anything to do with it. In my **android-library-module.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.library"
apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android"

android {
    compileSdk DefaultConfig.compileSdk

    defaultConfig {

        minSdk DefaultConfig.minSdk
        targetSdk DefaultConfig.targetSdk
        versionCode DefaultConfig.versionCode
        versionName DefaultConfig.versionName

        testInstrumentationRunner DefaultConfig.testInstrumentationRunner
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation Lib.androidXCoreKotlin
    implementation Lib.androidXAppCompat
    implementation Lib.googleMaterial
    implementation Lib.constraintLayout

    testImplementation Lib.junit

    androidTestImplementation Lib.androidXJunit
    androidTestImplementation Lib.espresso
    androidTestImplementation Lib.espressoIntents
    androidTestImplementation Lib.androidXTruth
    androidTestImplementation Lib.androidXRunner
    androidTestImplementation Lib.androidXRules
}
```

In my **common.build.gradle**:

`apply from: "$rootDir/android-library-build.gradle"`

In my **app.build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android"

android {
    compileSdk DefaultConfig.compileSdk

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId DefaultConfig.applicationId
        minSdk DefaultConfig.minSdk
        targetSdk DefaultConfig.targetSdk
        versionCode DefaultConfig.versionCode
        versionName DefaultConfig.versionName

        testInstrumentationRunner DefaultConfig.testInstrumentationRunner
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation project(Modules.common)
    implementation Lib.androidXCoreKotlin
    implementation Lib.androidXAppCompat
    implementation Lib.googleMaterial
    implementation Lib.constraintLayout

    testImplementation Lib.junit

    androidTestImplementation Lib.androidXJunit
    androidTestImplementation Lib.espresso
    androidTestImplementation Lib.espressoIntents
    androidTestImplementation Lib.androidXTruth
    androidTestImplementation Lib.androidXRunner
    androidTestImplementation Lib.androidXRules
}
```

In my **buildSrc.build.gradle.kts**:

```
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.`kotlin-dsl`

plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due to the BaseTest class being part of the androidTest directory in the common module.

Only files in the main directory get included in the build file. So the app module, when implementing the common project, will only get its main directory classes.

Solution is to move the classes to the main directory of the module.